# Java - LibGDX gdx-freetype fails to load two font sizes from single TTF

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx, truetype

I am trying to load two different sizes of the same font using the [gdx-freetype](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype) extension of LibGDX: size 24 and 72. For whatever reason, it doesn't load the 24 right because it looks like [garbage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jinch.png). This is very strange because it looks correct when I am not also loading the 72.

In my code I have tried loading both fonts using the same FreeTypeFontGenerator, and with two different generators. They both yield the same result as far as I can tell. Also, it doesn't seem to matter what order I load the two fonts: the 24 is always the one that looks bad. Here is my code for loading fonts:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("fontFile.ttf"));
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter param = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
param.size = 72;
font = generator.generateFont(param);
generator.dispose();

FreeTypeFontGenerator generator2 = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("fontFile.ttf"));
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter param2 = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
param2.size = 24;
smallFont = generator2.generateFont(param2);
generator2.dispose();
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there an error in the gdx-freetype extension? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I seems to have same experience of this, what I made it work is to comment `dispose` out, and my generator works normally. But maybe not for your case.

Comment: @Tokenyet I tried commenting out `dispose` and I'm still getting the same result. If this worked for you then maybe I am doing something wrong elsewhere in the code, although I can't imagine what it could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I fixed my own problem, and it had nothing to do with the way I was loading fonts, but the way I was **rendering** them. I was creating a `GlyphLayout` like so:

```
textLayout = new GlyphLayout(smallFont, "Sample Text");
```

and then rendered it like this:

```
font.draw(spriteBatch, textLayout, width, height);
```

The problem was that I was drawing the text with a different font than the one I used to generate the layout. If anyone reading this had a similar problem with gdx-freetype, make sure you're rendering the fonts right.